# How to prevent redirecting of http://domain.com/sub to http://www.domain.com/sub

Tags: redirect

I am having a big problem, I checked the redirection of my domain here http://www.redirectcheck.com/ then the result was

```
"http://domain.com/sub"

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2011 07:14:30 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Location: http://www.domain.com/sub/ Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Length: 326 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

"http://www.domain.com/sub/"

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2011 07:14:31 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Location: http://domain.com/sub/ Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Length: 322 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

"http://domain.com/sub/"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2011 07:14:31 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) X-Powered-By: PHP/5.1.6 Vary: Accept-Encoding Connection: close Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I wanted it to be like this:

When I go to "http://domain.com/sub" (no trailing slash) it should redirect to "http://domain.com/sub/"

And when I go to "http://www.domain.com/sub" (no trailing slash) it should redirect to "http://domain.com/sub/"

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following into your document root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.){0,1}.*[^/]$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Be aware though that other entries in your `.htaccess` file are likely to interfere with this, so you may want to remove some other entries.